# Simple KnockoutJS binding doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

There seems to be some error with my KnockoutJS script but I can't figure it out where it's coming from. Here is the HTML code:

```
    <h2>SendMessage</h2>

<div class="form-group" id="messageSender">
    <label>Select User Type</label>
    <select id="userType" data-bind="options: $parent.userTypes, optionsText: 'type', optionsValue: 'role'
            optionsCaption: 'Select a user type:', value: selectedUserType"></select><br/>
    <label>Select Reciepient</label>
    <select id="reciepient" data-bind="options: $parent.users, optionsText: 'fname', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedUser, visible: userTypeSelected"></select>
    <br />
    <label>Message Text</label>
    <textarea data-bind="value:messageText, visible: userTypeSelected"></textarea><br/>
    <button data-bind="click:sendMessage">Send</button>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  var messageModel =   function Message(sender_id, reciever_id, messageText) {

        var self = this;

        self.sender_id = ko.observable(sender_id);
        self.reciever_id = ko.observable(reciever_id);
        self.messageText = ko.observable(messageText);
        self.mdate = Date.now();

        //send ajax request to the api  to add a send
        self.addMessage = function () {

            var dataObject = ko.toJSON(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/messageapi",
                type: 'add',
                data: dataObject,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    self.sender_id(null);
                    self.reciever_id(null);
                    self.messageText('');

                    alert("Message send successfully!");
                }
            });

        }


    }

var messageViewModel = function () {

        var self = this;

        self.userTypeSelected = ko.observable();
        //List of roles
        self.userTypes = [
           { role: 2, type: "Teacher" },
           { role: 3, type: "Parent" }
        ];

        self.messageText = ko.observable();
        self.users = function () {

            var role = this.userTypeSelected;
            if (role === 2) {
                $.ajax(
              {
                  url: "/api/MessageApi/GetTeachers/" + role,
                  type: 'get',
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  success: function (data) {
                      return data;
                  },
                  fail: function () {
                      alert("Error occurred while sending data");
                  }
              });
            }


        };

        self.sendMessage = function () {
            alert("You clicked me!");//added this for testing whether the code works or not
        }

    }


    ko.applyBindings(new messageViewModel());
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is the user selects the type of user s/he wants to send a message to. After selecting the user type, the users are fetched from the database through a Web Api(I'm using asp.net mvc5) by making an ajax call and are displayed in a drop-down list . However, when I run the code following things doesn't seem to work:

- The first drop-down doesn't display anything. However, I have bound it to the *userTypes* array
- The send button doesn't respond to click events even though I have bound it to the *sendMessage* function.
- The second drop-down list's visibilty is controlled by the *userTypeSelected* value but it always shows.

There might also be problem's in my ajax calls but the above ones are the obvious problems

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work" to narrow down the problem a little as there are quite a few scrollbars in the code you've posted :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I have edited my question to explain the problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code

1. You are missing a comma in your `select` after

   optionsValue: 'role'
2. You shouldn't use `$parent` in your bindings just use the name of the property in `options: userTypes` and `options: users`

   ```
   <select id="userType" data-bind="options: userTypes, optionsText: 'type', optionsValue: 'role',
       optionsCaption: 'Select a user type:', value: selectedUserType"></select><br />
   <label>Select Reciepient</label>
   <select id="reciepient" data-bind="options: users, optionsText: 'fname', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedUser, visible: userTypeSelected"></select>
   ```
3. In you first `select`in this part: `value: selectedUserType`,
   `selectedUserType` property doesn't exist. Did you mean `value: userTypeSelected`?

   ```
   <select id="userType" data-bind="options: userTypes, optionsText: 'type', optionsValue: 'role',
       optionsCaption: 'Select a user type:', value: userTypeSelected">
   ```
4. You are missing `self.selectedUser = ko.observable();` in your viewModel
5. Your `var messageModel = function Message(...)` seems completly pointless as is not referenced anywhere.
6. `self.users = function()...` will not work this way. What you need is to setup a function in the `change` event in the first select to call the $.ajax to load `self.users = ko.observableArray()`

   - Replace `self.users = function()...` with `self.users = ko.observableArray()`
   - Add a `self.userTypeChanged` function to your viewModel that will call $.ajax and fill the results to the users observableArray.

     - You are missing a pair of () after `var role = self.userTypeSelected();`
     - In the `success` callback you need to fill the `users` observableArray: `self.users(data);`

This should be the `self.userTypeChanged` function

```
    self.userTypeChanged = function () {
        var role = self.userTypeSelected();
        if (role === 2) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/MessageApi/GetTeachers/" + role,
                type: 'get',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    self.users(data);
                },
                fail: function () {
                    alert("Error occurred while sending data");
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

7. Add the `change` event to the first select to call `userTypeChanged` :

   ```
   <select id="userType" data-bind="options: userTypes, optionsText: 'type', optionsValue: 'role',
       optionsCaption: 'Select a user type:', value: userTypeSelected, event: { change : userTypeChanged }"></select>
   ```

This is the complete code. I hope this helps

## HTML

```
<h2>SendMessage</h2>

<div class="form-group" id="messageSender">
    <label>Select User Type</label>
    <select id="userType" data-bind="options: userTypes, optionsText: 'type', optionsValue: 'role',
        optionsCaption: 'Select a user type:', value: userTypeSelected, event: { change : userTypeChanged }"></select><br />
    <label>Select Reciepient</label>
    <select id="reciepient" data-bind="options: users, optionsText: 'fname', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedUser, visible: userTypeSelected"></select>
    <br />
    <label>Message Text</label>
    <textarea data-bind="value:messageText, visible: userTypeSelected"></textarea><br />
    <button data-bind="click:sendMessage">Send</button>
</div>
```

## JS

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var messageViewModel = function () {

            var self = this;
            self.selectedUser = ko.observable();
            self.userTypeSelected = ko.observable();
            //List of roles
            self.userTypes = [
                { role: 2, type: "Teacher" },
                { role: 3, type: "Parent" }
            ];

            self.messageText = ko.observable();

            self.users = ko.observableArray();

            self.userTypeChanged = function () {
                var role = self.userTypeSelected();
                if (role === 2) {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "/api/MessageApi/GetTeachers/" + role,
                        type: 'get',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            self.users(data);
                        },
                        fail: function () {
                            alert("Error occurred while sending data");
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            self.sendMessage = function () {
                alert("You clicked me!");//added this for testing whether the code works or not
            }
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new messageViewModel());
    });
```

Comment: I added your suggestions and the first drop-down works. However, clicking the send button doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Does your second select loads? It looks like your `self.users` function is not well defined

Comment: You're right, it doesn't load. What I'm trying to do is load the users returned by the ajax call to the second select. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: There are a LOT of errors in your page like typos and javascript mistakes. Please debug your app with your browser developer tools before posting it to stackoverflow. Although I'm gonna keep editing my answer with all I can find

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write a wonderfully detailed answer. It's now working!